# Arrow typed errors library in java

Tags: java, kotlin, arrow-kt

It's not clear to if I'm able to use arrow typed error classes in java.

I've took a look on [arrow typed errors documentation here](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/).

I mean, I'm aware I'm able to import maven artifact dependency into my java project, but it's not clear to how to use its classes. Am I able to use `Either`, or `EitherKt`.

Which limitations am I going to face with?

I've played a bit, but I'm getting some compilation warnings:

```java
    public static Either<NonEmptyList<String>, Reference> of(ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier) {
        Either left = EitherKt.left("String");
        return left;
    }
```

Compilation warnings:

> Either is a raw type. References to generic type Either<A,B> should be parameterized Java (16777788) [30, 3]

> Type safety: The expression of type Either needs unchecked conversion to conform to Either<NonEmptyList,Reference> Java (16777748) [31, 10]

Comment: `Either` is a generic type, you you have to provide the generic type arguments: `Either<NonEmptyList<String>, Reference> left = …`. You are already specifying them in the method signature, so why do you omit them in the variable declaration?

Comment: The issue you're having with raw types is really unrelated to your core question about whether Arrow will work in Java. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321 to learn more about what that warning means.

Comment: My question was more related with if a kotlin library like arròs is fully compatible with Java.